# What is the difference between C++0x and C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I see mixed usage of these two terms here on SO.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11)

> C++11, also formerly known as C++0x ...

but I am not sure why.

- Why was it first called C++0x and then C++11?
- Also, what does the x stand for? My guess - like a variable?

Comment: Zero means that the writers of the spec were overly optimistic (aren't programmers always are like that?)

Comment: C++0x was a very optimistic name. Calling it DukeNukem, erm, C++4ever would have been more realistic.

Comment: I don't understand what the connection between a zero and optimism is.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger the zero represents optimism because people thought the standard would be finished in the decade of the 2000s and so would be called C++08 or C++09. In reality it was not finished until 2011.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I always thought the `0x` was meant to introduce a hexadecimal literal.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

C++ and C Standards are usually named after the year they are published in, which makes it easier to remember by.

For example, in C++, the original Standard was published in 1998, so we talk about C++98, and when we refer to its first correction, published in 2003, we talk about C++03.

It had been purported that the next Standard after would be done for 2008, but since it was uncertain, it was dubbed C++0x, where the `x` stood for either 8 or 9. In practice though, as we all know, the planning shifted and so we end-up with C++11.

Still, for the next version (C++1x), Bjarne Stroustrup stated his intent to do it in 5 years (so about 2016). For now, there are changes envisionned to the core language (concepts, modules and garbage collection), and the focus seems to be more on extending the library (filesystem for example), but it's still early so who knows!

Comment: There were a number of things pushed off to the next standard: concepts, garbage collection, modules...  (Garbage collection is probably the closest to being ready.  And modules still needs considerable work.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I had not heard of Garbage Collection and I had forgotten modules (thanks). Modules are actually quite easy by themselves (many languages have them already), I remember Doug Gregor saying that the real issue was actually bridging modules and the actual header system into a coherent whole so that you don't need to wait for your dependencies to migrate before you do. Doug has been working hard on integrating the modules in Clang, but posed a bit to polish off the lambdas for CLang 3.1 it seems.

Comment: message from the future, we have C++14 and C++17

Answer (score 33):

C++0x was the name for the standard before it was released / finalized. Once it was finalized (in the year 2011), we were able to name it properly. That is, C++11.

Comment: And according to Bjarne’s “the ‘x’ is hexadecimal” quip, it could also be C++0B. :P

Comment: @JonPurdy The original target was to have the final standard out before 2009. Bjarne made his comment concerning the x being hexadecimal went it became clear that we weren't going to make it.  (He may have meant it ironically.  I don't know.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, yeah. It’s a joke. Standard committees have to do *something* to lighten the mood.

Answer (score 6):

Because the standard was planned to be released / approved in `200x`, but actually was approved in `2011`.

Answer (score 5):

When work began on the new standard, in 1998 or so, no-one knew which year it would be finalised in - so the "x" stood for an unknown year, and a hope that it would be finalised within ten years or so.

In the end, it was finalised in 2011, and so the standard is now known colloquially as C++11, and officially as ISO/IEC 14882:2011.

Now that that standard is official, work is continuing on the next; again, no-one knows when that will be done, but it's hoped that it will take less than a decade, and so it's colloquially known as C++1x.