# program to capitalize all lowercase not working

Tags: c++

An assignment wants me to make a function that makes all lowercase characters uppercase.

Here's my code:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Function.h"//Includes function file in main file
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a;
    cout<<"Enter some words:";
    cin.get(a);//Collects info from user
    strcap(a);
    cout<<a;
}
```

function.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Function.h"
using namespace std;

char strcap(char a){
    while (a!='\n'){
        if (a>='a' && a<='z'){
            a-=32;//
        }
        cin.get(a); //get the next letter
    }
}
```

function.h:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

char strcap(char a);
```

Comment: How many chars do you think you can store in `char a;`? Use [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: Read [ask].  Then tell us exactly what you think is wrong with your program?  You told us what your assignment is, but you haven't described your debugging efforts or given us any input and output examples.

Comment: This code is the completely wrong way to go.  You need to start over and take a different approach. Look at the example code provided in [this `std::toupper()` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)

Comment: Use [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) to convert lower case to upper case.

Comment: You're changing a local variable in `strcap` and throwing it away, it's never used, never returned.

Answer (score 2):

While the approach you have taken approximates a standard C approach, you have not provided adequate storage to read more than a single character. You could wrap your `cin.get(a); strcap(a); cout << a;` in a `while` loop, that would be an approach that is about a decade out of place in C++. Using [std::basic::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) provides automatic memory management for your input and [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) makes it simple to apply a transformation to all elements of a container.

The example for [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) provides exactly what you need, but it doesn't explain how to split the operation up into a separate header and source file. If after reading the documentation you are still stuck, the you can do something similar to the following.

Your header for `function.h` as you have it simply needs to provide for the declaration of `strcap`, e.g.

```
#include <string>

void strcap (std::string& s);
```

Your implementation for `function.cpp` likewise just needs to provide for the definition of `strcap`:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

#include "function.h"

void strcap (std::string& s)
{
    std::transform (s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                    [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });
}
```

(**note:** the *trailing-return-type* `"-> unsigned char"` can be omitted above and it will be deduced properly)

Your `main.cpp` would then be:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "function.h"

int main (void) {

    std::string s;

    std::cout << "enter string: ";
    if (getline (std::cin, s)) {
        strcap(s);
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Compile as you normally would, but you will require the language standard of at least `-std=c++11`, and then, e.g.

```
$ ./main
enter string: My dog has fleas
MY DOG HAS FLEAS
```

Also note, if you do not want to use `std::transform`, you can use a range-based-for loop to iterate over each character in your string converting to uppercase as well. Your `strcap()` function would then be:

```
void strcap (std::string& s)
{
    for (auto& c : s)
        c = toupper(c);
}
```

And if for some reason your compiler doesn't support the *range-based* `for` loop, then you can also use basic `std::string:iterator` to iterate over the string providing the conversion, e.g.

```
void strcap (std::string& s)
{
    for (std::string::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++)
        *it = toupper(*it);
}
```

There are several different approaches you can take.

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

---

**Code::Blocks Compiler Options**

Just to make sure we are on the same sheet of paper, you should see:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I implemented what you said but I'm getting a bunch of expected primary expression errors in function.cpp.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you provide the `-std=c++11` language standard as part of the compile string and include all the headers? If your compiler does not provide the `<algorithms>` header (if for example you are using DevC++), then you may be limited to using the `for` loop example I just included as an edit -- or you may have to use a string::iterator if you do not have the range-based `for` loop.

Comment: I'm very new to this, Im not sure what to do with "-std=c++11". I am using codeblocks.

Comment: OK with codeblocks you likely have MinGW as your compiler. Hold on and I'll tell you where to include the standard. (I have to start a windows machine)

Comment: @JohnyJim In Code::Blocks, with your project open, choose `Project->Build options...`, then in the `Compiler Flags` dialog, you can check the box for `std=c++11` to ensure you have the features of c++11 available. You should also look at the top and confirm you have the `GNU GCC Compiler` selected. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Alright it runs now, but it doesn't work properly. I entered "my dog has fleas" but it returned "m"

Comment: You still didn't make all the changes. I just compiled on old Code::Blocks 16.01 on Win7 and got `C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\cb\toupper>bin\Release\toupper.exe` then `enter string: My dog has fleas` and the output of `MY DOG HAS FLEAS`. Did you have any compiler warnings? And you have all files as part of your project, right?

Comment: I think the issue is that when I go to the project build settings I don't have the option for -std=c++11. My apologies for not clarifying earlier.

Comment: OK, back to the what options do you have, and what compiler is shown at the top of the page? Generally Code::Blocks provides MinGW (which provides g++)? In the `Build options...` dialog, did you select your `Debug` or `Release` target and then look in the `Compiler Settings->Compiler Flags` tabs??

Comment: GNU GCC compiler, I looked through both debug and release and I don't have it.

Comment: Take a look at the image I just posted as an edit -- is that what you see for your `Compiler Options`? If you just select your project name at the top-left, it will set the option for both builds.

Comment: I see that but I don't have the -std=c++11 option.

Comment: There is something fishy here. Do you have any `"-std=c++..."` options as you scroll up/down in the `Compiler Flags` tab? There isn't any sneaky setting you have to set to see them -- this is generally automatic stuff?? I'm stumped on why you are not seeing them. You see the same thing when you check the `Settings` and then `Compiler...` menu?

Comment: I have ++98 and ++0x but not  ++11 here's a pic of my settings https://gyazo.com/081ccf154987d5c3456e56d1d1300994

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere -- you have an ancient version of MinGW...  It has to be pre-`4.92`... Change the version of `strcap` from the one with `tranform` to the last one I posted with the `std::string:iterator it = s.begin()...` and try again. I can't believe it let you compile without warnings (you do have `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` options checked --right??). Anyway, give one of the other versions a try -- you must not have a full implementation of the  STL. and check the `-std=c++0x` which will be your latest version.

Comment: You can also download and install and new [Code::Blocks release with MinGW](http://codeblocks.org/downloads/26) that will provide a current gcc/g++. You will really have problems going forward with an ancient compiler... The version 16.01 I have is 3+ years old and it provides through `-std=c++14` functionality -- yours must be really old...

Comment: Awesome. There is always a solution -- Good luck with your coding! You can also see [What is the difference between C++0x and C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538701/what-is-the-difference-between-c0x-and-c11) to understand better the differences in the language standard.