# Why does Code::blocks use both -std=c++0x and -std=c++11? Is there any difference between them? And why does Learncpp use -std=c++1x?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, codeblocks

In [Learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com) I found that c++1x is the code name of c++11.
And When I noticed Code::blocks IDE compiler flags, I saw that it uses the c++0x as coming C++ language standard of C++ 11.
Then I noticed that Code::blocks have both `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++0x` compiler flags in compiler flags option. If `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++0x` are same then why there there two flags instead of one. And if `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++0x` are not same and `-std=c++1x` is similar to `-std=c++11`, then what about `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++1y`? Why are there two different flags when both are same? That's why I asked that, ***"What are the differences between `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++1x`?"***

Comment: [What is the difference between C++0x and C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538841)

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Standardization) may help a bit.

Comment: -std=c++17 enables the C++17 language version. -std=c++0x and -std=c++1x are old names for -std=c++11 which enable the C++11 language version.

Comment: Note that Code::Blocks is a graphical wrapper (an IDE) for **any** compiler.  Your questions are about this compiler, which might be gcc.  And might be clang.  And might be something else.

Comment: More background reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history

Comment: *c++1x is the code name of c++11*  Not really, `c++1x` is a placeholder for what eventually became C++11.  The placeholder was there for compiler vendors to allow developers to use the forthcoming standard that was still in a state of flux before it was released, even though the compiler may have partial or incomplete or even incorrect (because they may have implemented something that changed over time and their version had become wrong) support.

Comment: Ok but this link doesm't answer the question fully. The user asked about differemce between c++11 and c++0x  and the person who answered the question said difference between c++0x and c++1x. And he said that they are previous name of c++11. But it means that three are same. Then why does codeblocks (gnu gcc compiler) have both compiler flags even when both indicates same thing, only the difference is, c++0x/c++1x is the older name of c++11? The difference is between the name and time. But aren't they have same effect?

Comment: *But aren't they have same effect?*  Maybe.  Maybe not.  Might depend on the compiler.  Some compilers might remove the now unnecessary (and potentially confusing) older names.

Comment: Your IDE needs to also support older compilers that only know the old name.

Comment: I am not saying about adding compiler flags via other compiler flags option in codeblocks. Im talking about the compiler extensions that can be ysed by checking the compiler flags in codeblocks' compiler flag list. Why did they make same thing if the compiler flags are same? And Im talking about gnu gcc compiler.

Comment: @rajin100000 the flags are not the same.  "c++0x"  means "use the possibly incomplete and possibly wrong features that may or may not become standard after C++03".  It's a flag that is available on compiler versions that didn't offer C++11, because that standard didn't exist at the time.

Comment: Oh, now I understood. So, c++0x was a incomplete c++11 version which may had bugs/wrong feature, but after completing the standard, it was named c++11. Am I right?